# why there is error of 'NameError: name 'position' is not defined'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it that when I run this code, the error is

> 'name position is not defined??'

I think I have already defined `position` before call it

the code is for using *`r,l,i,d`* to change the *`position(x,y)`*

```
def get_position_in_direction(position, direction):

    position=(0,1)
    x,y=position
    direction=input("Please enter an action (enter '?' for help): ")

    if direction=='r':
        xi,yi=(1,0)
    elif direcrion=='l':
        xi,yi=(-1,0)
    elif direction=='u':
        xi,yi=(0,1)
    elif direction=='d':
        xi,yi=(0,-1)
    else:
       pass
    position=position+xi,yi
    return position
print(get_position_in_direction(position, direction))
```

Comment: You define position inside the function (line 3) move it outside (line 1 or second to last)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: "i think i have already defined position before call it" Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

I find several problems in your code:

- When you call it, in this line: `print(get_position_in_direction(position, direction))`, `position` and `direction` are not defined
- The parameters `direction` and `position` are useless as input for the function, because you update them afterwards, so let's remove the lines where you update them
- In the `if`-`else` statements there is a misspelling, you wrote `direcrion` instead of `direction`.
- This line does not do what you want to do. See below the way of doing it correctly: `position=position+xi,yi`
- If you enter a wrong direction, `xi` and `yi` will be undefined. Let's drop a controlled error in that case

The correct code would be:

```
def get_position_in_direction(position, direction):

    x,y=position    
    if direction=='r':
        xi,yi=(1,0)
    elif direction=='l':
        xi,yi=(-1,0)
    elif direction=='u':
        xi,yi=(0,1)
    elif direction=='d':
        xi,yi=(0,-1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("The value specified for the direction"
                         "parameter is not recognised as a valid parameter")
    position=(position[0]+xi, position[1]+yi)
    return position

position = (0,0)
direction = 'l'
print(get_position_in_direction(position, direction))
```

Comment: if you enter the `else` block, then `xi, yi` would be undefined. Therefore you could trigger an error still.
Also, according to your logic about `direction`, `position might as well be removed as an argument`.

Comment: I completely agree with you. See my updated code. Thanks